# Access @Test method variables outside of that in integration test

Tags: java, variables, junit, annotations, integration-testing

How can I access the value of @Test method outside of that method.

```
 @Test(groups = {"cookie"})
    public void loginAndExecute(@NonNull TestCaseInput testCaseInput) {
        LoginComponents loginComponents = null;
        initializeDriver();
    
        try {
            loginComponents = PageModelBuilder.builder(this.driver).withDesktopClass(DesktopLoginComponents.class).build();
            Map<String,String> mp = loginComponents.getSecret();
            actualAPIResponse = loginComponents.loginAndValidate(mp);
           }
}
```

I want to access the actualAPIResponse inside another java class. How can I do that ?

Comment: `I want to access the actualAPIResponse inside another java class. How can I do that ?` , do you mean another java method of same Test class?

Comment: No, inside another java class

Comment: create `actualAPIResponse` as class member field of current class & access it via getter setter in another class